# Modify axis on plotted model to log scale

Tags: r, lme4, sjplot

I want to use the shown plot and generated it with plot_model(model, type="int") using sjPlot. But as you can see since one of the graphs overshoots by a lot the others can't be read properly. So i would like to scale the y-axis logarithmicly. How can i achieve this ? (R beginner so maybe i am missing the obvious)

[image]

Comment: Can't you just log-transform your response in the model? E.g., `fit <- lmer(log(response) ~ x1*x2 + (1|group), data = your_data)`

Comment: yes i could, but since this is just for a "nicer plot" - changing the base idea of my model sounds not like the best idea ? I would definitively prefer to change the view of my model rather then my model itself. But if i can't find any way i will come back to your idea. Thanks